# How to combine Arrangement.spacedBy() and Arrangement.Center in a Row.horizontalArrangement

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

Is it possible to combine `Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)` and `Arrangement.Center` in a `Row.horizontalArrangement`?

What I would like to do is to center the content horizontally and also set a default spacing of `16.dp`.

I know that I can combine the `Row` and a `Box` to achieve the same result but I was wondering if can be done with just he `Row`'s properties.

```kotlin
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, // I would like to add the .spacedBy(16.dp), keeping the Center arrangement 
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.generic_error_pagination),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.textSecondary,
        )
        OutlinedButton(onClick = onClick) {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.retry_button))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [`spacedBy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#spacedBy(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal)) variant with the `alignment` parameter:

> An `alignment` can be specified to align the spaced children horizontally inside the parent

```kotlin
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement
            .spacedBy(
                space = 16.dp, 
                alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, that was easy! I tried to use that variant but I missed the `Alignment.CenterHorizontally`. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! The fact that `Arrangement.spacedBy` accepts an `Alignment` as an argument is a bit counter-intuitive, isn't it?

Comment: @ArthurKhazbulatov A bit? Half the Jetpack Compose APIs are counterintuitive.

Comment: @joshgalv Stay strong, fellow developer, we can do it

Comment: Why it need to apply alignment modifier in spaceBy modifier, it is weird.